# Devise for Rails: Does Seperating User Data into Two Models Improve Security?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

I am building a rails app using Devise. I have been told that it is advisable to split User data into two Models for security reasons... 1 Model being the default User table created by devise, and the other a Profile table to store private data (addresses etc).

As explained in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029542/devise-for-rails-4-why-should-you-keep-user-profile-data-on-a-separate-table-to), its a good idea to do this for Separation of Concern reasons.

My question is, does doing this also increase security of the user accounts, or not?

My guess is that it would not, because if someone has hacked into your database then it would not matter how many Models you have data scattered across, the hacker would have access to all of it anyway. But happy to be corrected if I am wrong :)

Comment: No. This are no intrinsic security benefits to splitting the details of a user into separate tables/models. Creating a completely separate resource increases complexity but on the other hand you don't have to monkey with devise controllers and views which could potentially lead to security holes if you mess it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Your point about having access to the database is valid. If that happens, you're right; it won't matter how the data is structured.

The point that the article that you referenced is also valid. If the `User` model is specifically in place to interact with `devise`, it might be best not to use it to store profile information for maintainability reasons, if nothing else.

If `devise` is the only library that controls migrations to the `User` table, you're much less likely to run into migration or column name conflicts down the road.

That said, I'd agree with the separation of concerns approach.